# Recursive counter without a loop

Tags: c++, recursion, count, void

I'm trying to write a recursive version of the following code without using loops.

```
static void count (){   
    for ( int i =0; i <=10; i++) System.out.println(i);
}
```

I can do it as a static int, but I can't get it as a void.

Thanks!

Comment: what is your error? your question isn't very clear...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a recursive function for your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void count(int x)
{
        if (x == 0)
        {
                return;
        }
        cout<<x<<endl;
        count(x-1);
}

int main()
{
        count(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want count from 0 to 10 you could do it with 2 parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void count(int start, int end)
{
        if (start == end)
        {
                return;
        }
        cout << start << endl;
        count(++start, end);
}

int main()
{
        count(0, 10);
}
```